# Recover Chrome passwords from laptop drive

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery

I have a failed laptop which has some passwords stored in the Chrome browser.

Unfortunately, it seems that some of the passwords were not properly synced with the cloud before the laptop failed, so I am unable to log into some sites from my backup computer as the passwords stored appear to be incorrect.

Is there a way to recover and sync the passwords stored on the (still functioning) hard drive of the old laptop?

Comment: Copy the user profile for the Chrome installation after you connect the HDD by a USB docking station.  This assumes the drive is in a working condition and the volume can be mounted.  If it cannot be mounted then the data cannot be recovered.

Comment: @Ramhound So I've copied over the user profile from the original hard drive to the installation of Chrome on the backup computer. It works and restores my bookmarks and even the tabs I had open, but unfortunately the "passwords" section of the advanced settings is blank. The ChromePass app shows all the sites, but the password field is blank for them. Anything else to try?

Answer (score -1):

make hirens boot cd ( acutally win 10 usb ), search for chromepass download unzip using password below download link, to its own folder, copy folder to root of hirens boot usb.   boot on failed laptop, run chromepass, select advanced options select path for failed laptop, provie login

you MUST KNOW FALIED LAPTOP LOGIN PASSWORD FOR THIS TO WORK

seems to only work for local accounts not live ID.
chrome uses login password to excrypt website passwords